# Forward declarations and cross-referencing in tuples

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, forward-declaration, cross-reference

There are plenty of questions regarding C++ forward declarations in StackOverflow, but nothing I found addresses this issue.

Consider the following code:

```
struct Record1; // Forward declaration.
struct Record2; // Forward declaration.

struct Record1 {int a; Record2 *r2;};
struct Record2 {int b; Record1 *r1;};
```

It's compilable and usable. Now, say I would like to use tuples, instead of structs. Is that possible? It seems I can't avoid needing some sort of (an illegal) forward declaration for typedefs, e.g:

```
class Record1;
class Record2;

using Record1 = std::tuple<int, Record2*>; // No go. Conflicting declaration.
using Record2 = std::tuple<int, Record1*>; // Same here.
```

I've tried several approaches, including desperately abusing late template instantiation, but with no success. I would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to alias the name of a `class` as a `tuple` that's not legal C++ code.

Comment: I know it's illegal (it says so in my post...). But notice that both  examples are pretty much equivalent, so I'd expect that since the first is feasible, so would be the second. If it's the case that std::tuple is preferable over structs without the cross-references, then it remains true with the cross-references, and I would like to use it.

Comment: @Borbei no, `class Record1;` forward declares a type. `using Record1 = ...` defines a type alias, not a type.

Comment: Yes, I know. I hoped I made it clear in the question (obviously, I didn't). My question is rather simple: How can I make the fist example work with tuples instead of structs?

Comment: You understand that `struct`s are just `class`es with all their members public? `struct Record1` is a name identifier for a `class` type. If you declare the same identifier as an alias how the hack the compiler is going to distinguish between the type and the alias?

Comment: The second example is ILLUSTRATIVE. I know it's illegal. I know why it's illegal.

Comment: Hope this clear things up. In the example you posted the names `Record1` and `Record2` are used as the names for `struct Record1` and `struct Record2`. Then you say, that `Record1`, `Record2` will be aliases for `std::tuple<int, Record2*>` and `std::tuple<int, Record1*>` respectively. The compiler now comes and says: "Hey dude! At first you told that these names are going to be used as `struct` (i.e., types) and then you want me to change their use to be tuples, I'm confused I can't do the thing you asked. What these name should represent a `struct` or a `tuple`? Please decide...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abusing public inheritance is a way to get what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class Record1;
class Record2;

class Record1: public std::tuple<int, Record2*> { using base = std::tuple<int, Record2*>; using base::base; };
class Record2: public std::tuple<int, Record1*> { using base = std::tuple<int, Record1*>; using base::base; };

int main() 
{
    Record1 r1 = std::make_tuple(0, nullptr);        
    std::cout << (std::get<0>(r1) == 0) << (std::get<1>(r1) == nullptr);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc84fac1b2d328c3).

Comment: Thanks! But I think those Record1 and Record2 classes can't be practically used as tuples without some additional wrapping that would make this solution inconvenient. For example, "Record1 r1 = std::make_tuple(0, nullptr);" won't work.

Comment: @Borbei just add a typedef to declare the base class and then use inheriting constructors, and you are all set. See updated answer.

Comment: The compiler I'm using doesn't support constructors inheritance, but your solution does seem to be complete. Thanks!